# How can I create a pocket door locking mechanism?

Tags: lock, pocket-door

Anyone know how I can make a pocket door lock? My brain is designing a few but can't figure our the best materials. I used to have a chain slide lock but i had to break into my room.

Comment: Is it one you have to make? There are pocket door lock available....

Comment: Any reason you can't just replace the slide lock you broke?

Comment: suspicious.  Chain slide locks are locked by the occupant of a room from the secure side.  How would you have had to break into your room?

Comment: Voting to close. Fabrication of readily-available hardware isn't home improvement.

Answer (score 1):

My pocket doors have large, easy-to-use, visible latching mechanisms.  We had the pocket doors installed in extra-wide door openings, so that 4 inches of each pocket door is exposed when the door is in the fully-open position.  This leaves room for a large handle and the latch.

The latches are labelled JAKO® [INOX](http://www.unisonhardware.com/).  The handles are labelled JAKO®.  My door handles are 3/4" thick and about 7 1/4" from center-to-center, so they are more similar to Don-Jo's [door handles](http://www.doorware.com/site/product.cfm?id=216926) than to Jako's [current model](http://www.jako.biz/product-p/mod.chcp013vir.htm).

Inox also offers a line of [pocket door locks](http://www.unisonhardware.com/products/Pocket-Door-Lock-Res/).

Answer (score 0):

[Barn door lock](http://www.xlerp.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/The-Sliding-Door-Company-For-Sliding-Barn-Door-Hardware-Amazing-Door-Slide-Lock.jpg)

Here is a door slide lock just mount vertically.